# Moving and resizing MindMap elements – TikZ – child nodes and canvas

Tags: tikz-trees, mindmaps

Earlier I asked [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45496/adding-child-nodes-to-child-nodes-in-tikz-mindmap#comment93303_45496) question to help me adapt a mind map.

Now, I need to move and resize some elements and I don't know how – can someone advise?

[image: My Mind map in progress]

I need…

1. To move the Orange elements down and to the left;
2. To understand how to control placing of the child nodes
3. To be able to control the size of nodes and text
4. To make my title in the centre of a larger canvas.

Source code:

```
% Author: Edd Turner
% Source: Die Wahrnehmung
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Die Wahrnehmung}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {Sensorische Prozesse}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {Sinnes\-organe} }
      child { node[concept] {Schwellen}
      child {node[concept] {absolute Schwelle}}
        child {node[concept] {Unterschiedsschwelle}}
        }
        child { node[concept] {Optische Täuschungen aufgrund sensorischer Prozesse} 
          }
      } 
      child[concept color=blue] {
        node[concept] {Organisation}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child { node[concept] {Hauptsatz} }
        child { node[concept] {Gestaltgesetze} }
      }
      child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {Klassifikation}
       }
      child[concept color=orange]{ 
      node[concept] {Personenwahrnehmung}
       [clockwise from=-90]
         child { node[concept] {Theorie der Eindrucksbildung}
      child {node[concept] {erste Info (erster) Eindruck}}
      child {node[concept] {implizite Persönlichkeitstheorie}}
      child {node[concept] {Stereotype/Vorurteile}}
      child {node[concept] {selbsterfüllende Prophezeiung}}
      child {node[concept] {Halo-Effekt}}
      child {node[concept] {logischer Fehler}}
      child {node[concept] {Kontrastfehler}}
      child {node[concept] {Ähnlichkeitsfehler}}
      child {node[concept] {Attribution}}
      child {node[concept] {Person als Rollenträger}}
      child {node[concept] {Interpretation von Verhalten}}
      }
        child { node[concept] {Personen\-wahrnehmung als Beobachtung} }
        };
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The example you have provided is quite complicated. You should try to reduce the problem to a smaller example and then it will be easier to learn as you can try adjusting the parameters and see the results.  You will also get faster responses to your answers if the questions are more focused.

I have not used `mindmap` before, but from the documentation, here are a few of the things you can do to control the placement:

- To move some elements down just add `yshift=-<size>` where `<size>` is some measurement. Below I used `yshift=-5.0cm`.
- To control the placing you can specify `grow=<angle>` to specify in which directions the node should be placed..
- To size is controlled by the text in the node. You can specify a minimum size with the options `minimum size=<size>`.

I have applied some of the above to obtain:

[image]

While this does not solve all your problems it should help you get going. Try adjusting the various angles and see the effects to learn, which is exactly what I was doing in working with your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Die Wahrnehmung}
    [clockwise from=140]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
        node[concept] {Sensorische Prozesse}
            [clockwise from=120]
        child { node[concept] {Sinnes\-organe} }
        child { node[concept] {Schwellen}
            child {node[concept] {absolute Schwelle}}
            child {node[concept] {Unterschiedsschwelle}}
        }
        child { 
            node[concept] {Optische Täuschungen aufgrund sensorischer Prozesse} 
        }
    } 
    child[concept color=blue, grow=60, xshift=1cm, yshift=2cm] {
        node[concept] {Organisation}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child { node[concept] {Hauptsatz} }
        child { node[concept] {Gestaltgesetze} }
    }
    child[concept color=red, grow=-60] { 
        node[concept] {Klassifikation}
    }
    child[concept color=orange,yshift=0.5cm, grow=240]{ 
        node[concept] {Personenwahrnehmung}
            [clockwise from=-90]
            child { node[concept] {Theorie der Eindrucksbildung}
                child {node[concept] {erste Info (erster) Eindruck}}
                child {node[concept] {implizite Persönlichkeitstheorie}}
                child {node[concept] {Stereotype/Vorurteile}}
                child {node[concept] {selbsterfüllende Prophezeiung}}
                child {node[concept] {Halo-Effekt}}
                child {node[concept] {logischer Fehler}}
                child {node[concept] {Kontrastfehler}}
                child {node[concept] {Ähnlichkeitsfehler}}
                child {node[concept] {Attribution}}
                child {node[concept] {Person als Rollenträger}}
                child {node[concept] {Interpretation von Verhalten}}
            }
        child {node[concept] {Personen\-wahrnehmung als Beobachtung} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd managed to suss the angles last night on the train, but the grow command is something new. I'm sure I'l get there in the end…

Comment: Isn't there a method a figure out the positions automatically so that the node will not cover each other?

Comment: @qed: I haven't used the `mindmap` library for a while, so I think it is best if you post a new question along with a _small_ example that reproduces your specific problem.