# Why does babel not work in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyphenation, babel, mindmaps

[Adding child nodes to child nodes in TikZ Mindmap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45496/adding-child-nodes-to-child-nodes-in-tikz-mindmap) has some example code, where German words are not hyphenated correctly. I was trying to fix it by using `inputenc` (for Umlaute) and `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. Unfortunately it has no effect on hyphenation.

What must be changed?

Below you can see a Working Example of it, showing forced hyphenation and no hyphenation:
[image: close up of compiled MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
        node[concept] {Die Wahrnehmung}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child[concept color=green!50!black] {
        node[concept] {Sensorische Prozesse}
        [clockwise from=90]
        child { node[concept] {Schwellen} 
child {node[concept] {Unterschiedsschwelle}}
child {node[concept] {Unter\-schieds\-schwel\-le}}
}
} 
child[concept] { node[concept] {Klassifikation} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reason is that TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. Inserting `\hspace{0pt}` for example would enable hyphenation, because then the word is not at the very beginning:

```
child {node[concept] {\hspace{0pt}Unterschiedsschwelle}}
```

Comment: Insightful answer! I didn't think of that rule because it applies so rarely.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, if it's possible to add `\hspace{0pt}` automatically to the beginning of the code for every node content? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One can abuse the `font=` key in the node's options, to add the `\hspace{0pt}` macro at the beginning of the node. However this overwrites previous font keys, if present.

```
child {node[concept,font={\hspace{0pt}}] {Unterschiedsschwelle}}
```

In order to preserve the existing `font` keys, you can define the following in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{add to font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}}
\makeatother
```

then use it as

```
child {node[concept,add to font={\hspace{0pt}}] {Unterschiedsschwelle}}
child {node[concept,add to font={\hspace{0pt}}] {Unter\-schieds\-schwel\-le}}
```

to obtain

[image]