# Why the extra line in my tabular, using beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

Below is a minimal example that displays my problem. In the top row I have an `\onslide<+->` command that seems to introduce an extra vertical space in the table, which is not there (as desired) in the second row, when this command is not present. Why is this happening, and how can I remove the extra vertical space?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Minimal Example}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.32\textwidth}|X}\hline
left & middle & \onslide<+-|handout:0>{right}\\\hline
left & middle & right\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47609/using-beamer-visible-command-inside-a-table-without-adding-vertical-space

Comment: @dcmst Indeed, your linked question has a satisfactory solution. Perhaps my question counts as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\only<...>` instead of `\onslide<...>`

Comment: This indeed does work. But is your answer suggesting that one should use `\only` instead of `\onslide` throughout, or just in such circumstances?

Comment: in this case: `\only` reserves no space when not active