# How to draw a cycle diagram in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a similar diagram.

Every block would be connected to the one following clockwise using a -> arrow.

They would all have different labels in them.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [PowerPoint's “Smart Art” for TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78310/powerpoints-smart-art-for-tikz), that seems to be exactly what you're looking for

Comment: sorry but I am a beginner and it seems to difficult to follow

Comment: Claudio turned the code from his answer into a package, [smartdiagram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram), which is available in TeXLive and MikTeX. It has great documentation with plenty of examples.