# TikZ: adding nodes to a circular diagram from smartdiagram package

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, smartdiagram

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\smartdiagramset{%
circular distance=40mm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=20mm,
module minimum width=30mm,
module minimum height=30mm,
module shape=diamond,
arrow tip=to,
%uniform arrow color=true,
arrow color=gray!50!black,
border color=black,
set color list={white,white,white,white,white,white}
}

\tikzstyle{mystyle}=[align=center,fill=white,drop shadow,draw,thick,circle,overlay,minimum width=20mm,text width=25mm]

\begin{document}
~\vfill
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{a, b, c, d, e, f}
\tikz \node (a) [mystyle,above=10mm of module1] {Start}; 
\tikz \node (b) [mystyle,right=10mm of module6] {Finish};
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=to]
\path[->,gray!50!black,line width=3pt,fill=gray!50!black] (a) edge (module1);
\path[->,gray!50!black,line width=3pt,fill=gray!50!black] (module6) edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

I would achieve a similar result in a more intuitive way. As you can see I needed to go inside `smartdiagram.sty` to know how the nodes were named, and then I need to use the `overlay`. Moreover, suggestions for start and finish are welcome.

Comment: The given MWE has a compilation error: `/smart diagram/u
niform arrow color` is an unknown pgfkey. Also, please don't use the `minimal` class -- `article` is a good one to use.  See [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class).

Comment: Edit done. With the latest TeXLive 2012 it complies. Note that it requires 2 runs to put nodes at correct position.

Comment: Still does not compile for me for the same reason as above. I have a fairly recent TeXLive2012. Are you perhaps using a non-released version of some library?

Comment: I am using a vanilla installation. Also I am not using any non-released library. However, I did a small editing to see if you can compile it.

Comment: I can compile it, _only_ if I comment out the `\smartdiagramset{....}`.

Comment: Ok. That shall give you a flavor of what I want. I also added a picture.

Comment: @PeterGrill: the `/smart diagram/uniform arrow color` is a new key available from version 0.2, on CTAN for a week.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

With version 0.3 (already sent on CTAN and thus available on TeXLive in few days) of the package to create such a diagram is a bit easier.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions} % library to create annotations 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{%
 circular distance=40mm,
 text width=20mm,
 module minimum width=30mm,
 module minimum height=30mm,
 module shape=diamond,
 arrow tip=to,
 uniform arrow color=true,
 arrow color=gray!50!black,
 border color=black,
 uniform color list=white for 6 items, % new key to make colors uniform easily
 circular final arrow disabled=true, % new key to remove the final arrow
 additions={
   additional item offset=15mm,
   additional item shape=circle,
   additional item border color=black,
   additional item shadow=drop shadow,
   additional arrow color=gray!50!black,
 }
}
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{a, b, c, d, e, f}{
above of module1/Start,right of module6/End}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{additional-module1/module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{module6/additional-module2}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

This method does not suffer anymore of the limitation on the number of additions that can be added.

---

*First version*

First of all a disclaimer: the solution I provide *works* if and only if one has to add just a *start* and an *end* to the diagrams.

It provides a new command `\smartdiagramadd` able to set the usual diagram plus the start/end: it receives 3 arguments:

1. type of diagram
2. list of elements in the diagram
3. `position/text` of the start, `position/text` of the end (for example: `above/Start,right/End`).

It can be used as:

```
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{a, b, c, d, e, f}{above/Start,right/End}
```

Moreover, the solution allows to customize the distance of the start/end modules by means of two new keys:

```
\pgfkeys{/smart diagram/.cd,
  add start module offset/.initial=10mm,
  add start module offset/.get=\addstartmodoffset,
  add start module offset/.store in=\addstartmodoffset,
  add end module offset/.initial=10mm,
  add end module offset/.get=\addendmodoffset,
  add end module offset/.store in=\addendmodoffset,
}
```

They should be used always within `\smartdiagramset`; for example:

```
\smartdiagramset{add end module offset=20mm}
```

Now, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfkeys{/smart diagram/.cd,
  add start module offset/.initial=10mm,
  add start module offset/.get=\addstartmodoffset,
  add start module offset/.store in=\addstartmodoffset,
  add end module offset/.initial=10mm,
  add end module offset/.get=\addendmodoffset,
  add end module offset/.store in=\addendmodoffset,
}

\smartdiagramset{%
circular distance=40mm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=20mm,
module minimum width=30mm,
module minimum height=30mm,
module shape=diamond,
arrow tip=to,
uniform arrow color=true,
arrow color=gray!50!black,
border color=black,
set color list={white,white,white,white,white,white}
}

\tikzset{module start-end/.style={
  align=center,
  fill=white,
  drop shadow,
  draw,
  thick,
  circle,
  minimum width=20mm,
  text width=25mm}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramadd}{r[] m m}{
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\smartdiagram[#1]{#2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\numitems\xi}
\StrCut{#3}{,}\startdiagram\enddiagram
% start
\StrCut{\startdiagram}{/}\pos\textitem
 \node (module1-start) [module start-end,\pos=\addstartmodoffset of module1] {\textitem}; 
 \path[->,gray!50!black,line width=3pt,fill=gray!50!black] 
  (module1-start) edge (module1);
% end
\StrCut{\enddiagram}{/}\pos\textitem 
 \node (module\numitems-end) [module start-end,\pos=\addendmodoffset of module\numitems] {\textitem};
 \path[->,gray!50!black,line width=3pt,fill=gray!50!black] 
  (module\numitems) edge (module\numitems-end); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{add end module offset=20mm}
\smartdiagramadd[circular diagram]{a, b, c, d, e, f}{above/Start,right/End}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives (similar to the picture provided by the OP, but the end module is far):

[image]

#### Disclaimer

This solution just work with `smartdiagram` version 0.2 which already loads `xstring`, otherwise the package should be loaded separately.

Comment: This is a wonderful improvement for the package: thanks cacamailg. I even realize that in order to have an uniform color also for the modules a new key should be added (similar to what happens for arrows) because the actual solution is not practicable (set a whole list of white). These will be the next things implemented :)

Comment: Thanks. The solution can still be improved. For example, I would like to have an open circular diagram, this is, between `a` and `f` no arrow. A new key, e.g., `\smartdiagramaddnode` for adding nodes `above`, `below`, `in between two nodes` would be good. Also, if you want to add a new arrow for an node outside the circle, there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: @cacamailg: there's always room for improvements `:)` I think the open circular diagram can be easily done; something more difficult can be the `\smartdiagramaddnode` (are you think about it for some annotations?), but in principle could be addressed, even if I think `in between two nodes` may require a bit of work. However, to keep clear the site is always better ask one question at a time.

Comment: Yes. I was just giving you ideas to improve your package :P.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I have a [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469473/how-to-add-text-above-some-arrows) where I can't seem to put text on top of the arrows, are you able to help me?