# How to connect nodes with circular arcs in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, node-connections

I need creating a diagram like the one in the picture below. After creating nodes, how do I connect them with circular arcs centered at the centre of the triangle?
[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: Hello, could you show us what did you begin to write ? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe

Comment: I've seen a question like this before...

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103663/4778, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254849/4778, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146212/4778. But I'm sure there are more.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78310/powerpoints-smart-art-for-tikz?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

I finally obtained the desired result adapting a code by [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\Ray}{3cm}
% three differently shaped nodes on a circle
\node[rectangle,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,name path=n1] (A) at (-30:\Ray) {Text A};
\node[rectangle,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,name path=n2] (B) at (90:\Ray) {Text B};
\node[rectangle,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,name path=n3] (C) at (210:\Ray) {Text C};
% the circle I wish the connectors to be placed on
\path[name path=c] circle (\Ray);
\path[name intersections={of=n1 and c,name=i1},
      name intersections={of=n2 and c,name=i2},
      name intersections={of=n3 and c,name=i3}
     ];
% arcs
\begin{scope}
\pgfsetarrowsstart{Stealth[scale=1.5]}
\pgfsetarrowsend{Stealth[scale=1.5]}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{i3-1}{center}}
\pgfpatharcto{\Ray}{\Ray}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{i2-1}{center}}
\pgfusepath{draw}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{i1-2}{center}}
\pgfpatharcto{\Ray}{\Ray}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{i3-2}{center}}
\pgfusepath{draw}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{i2-2}{center}}
\pgfpatharcto{\Ray}{\Ray}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointanchor{i1-1}{center}}
\pgfusepath{draw}
\end{scope}
% labels on arcs
\node[rectangle,fill=white] at (20:\Ray) {Label 1};
\node[rectangle,fill=white] at (160:\Ray) {Label 2};
\node[rectangle,fill=white] at (270:\Ray) {Label 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result.
[image]

Thank you all for the info!