# Optional args for TikZ style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, arguments

I have a defined a TikZ style "midcircle" that decorates a path with, say, a small circle in the middle (with the decorations.markings library, setting "pos=0.5"). E.g.

```
\draw (0,0)edge[midcircle](1,0);
```

would draw a straight line with a circle in the middle. Now I would like to be able to change the position of the circle by defining another style, say "midcirclepos", such that e.g.

```
\draw (0,0)edge[midcircle,midcirclepos=0.7](1,0);
```

would draw the circle at "pos=0.7" instead "pos=0.5". I think I've seen such constructions, but I can't find any more how to implement it.

By the way, I can't use the usual default arguments for TikZ styles, because my "midcircle" already takes other arguments that also have defaults.

Comment: just put a variable in the value that you want to change like pos=#1 in your tikz style definition, then put the value midcircle=0.5, or another value like in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446637/154390) see how it is defined InLineArrow style,

Comment: @JLeonV.: This doesn't work for me: The thing is that I want to have pos=0.5 as the default value, but I also have 2 other arguments passed to "midcircle" one of which also has a default value. However TikZ cannot handle more than one default value. (See last sentence)

Comment: My first guess would be that the `pos=0.7` still works, because it is a `/tikz` key and not a `/pgf/decoration` key. Otherwise you could use `\tikzset{midcirclepos/.forward to=/tikz/pos}`, but without an MWE who knows for certain.

Comment: @AndiBauer, there is a good answer from gernot , and some that I learn too +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a key `midcirclepos` that takes as argument a value and stores it in the macro `\midcirclepos`. Initialize it with `0.5` and use `\midcirclepos` to access the value.

```
\tikzset{midcirclepos/.store in=\midcirclepos,midcirclepos=0.5}
```

Here is an example that also shows that the change to `midcirclepos` is temporary.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{midcirclepos/.store in=\midcirclepos,midcirclepos=0.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  midcircle/.style = {
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration = {
      markings,
      mark = at position \midcirclepos
        with {\draw (0,0) circle (0.1);}
    },
  }
]
  \draw (0,0) edge [midcircle] (1,0);
  \draw (0,-1) edge [midcircle,midcirclepos=0.7] (1,-1);
  \draw (0,-2) edge [midcircle] (1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot What's wrong with macros in the context of a macro machine like TeX? Accessing a macro seems to be lightweight compared to `\pgfkeysvalueof`.