# How do I label parts of a graph in the xy-coordinate plane?

Tags: pgfplots

[image: m]

I am using `pgfplots` and `tikz`, and below is the code I have for now.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            axis line style={=>},
            xmin=-1,xmax=5,
            ymin=-1,ymax=5,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels=\empty,
            yticklabels=\empty,
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,very thick,black,-]{-(x-(3/2))^2+(25/8)};
        \draw (0,0) coordinate  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What is the code for labeling:

1. the origin with the letter O?
2. the x-intercept (4,0)
3. the x and y values of the vertex on the x and y axes
4. dashed lines leading to the vertex
5. the label y=f(x) on top of the parabola

Bottomline: I am trying to plot a graph that looks exactly like the one in the image attached.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ti*k*Z allows you to declare functions and parses expressions in a path, so you might do:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=-(\x-(3/2))^2+(25/8);}]
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            axis line style={=>},
            xmin=-1,xmax=5,
            ymin=-1,ymax=5,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels=\empty,
            yticklabels=\empty,
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,very thick,black,-]{f(x)};
        \path (0,0) node[below left]{$O$};
        \draw[dashed] (0,{f(3/2)}) node[left]{$\frac{25}{8}$}-- (3/2,{f(3/2)})
        node[above right]{$y=f(x)$} -- (3/2,0) node[below]{$\frac{3}{2}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course `\path (0,0) node[below right]{$O$};` looks better.

Comment: Thank you for your help.You are amazing. I have another question.
When I add `\path (4,0) node[below]{4};` to the code (in order to make the x-intercept explicit), the 4 lies much farther to the right than it should. Is there a way to fix this problem besides brute-force changing `\path (4,0) node[below]{4};` to `\path (3,0) node[below]{4};`?

Comment: @SamChoi Did you add `\path (4,0) node[below]{4};` before or after `\end{axis}`? If you add it after, then the result is off because the coordinates of the ambient `tikzpicture` do not coincide with the ones of the `axis`. If you put it inside, the result looks consistent to me. Note that the parabola crossed the horizontal axis at `(6 + 5*sqrt(2))/4`, not at `4`.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I added  `\path (4,0) node[below]{4};` before the `\end{axis}`. I just found out that the graph itself is a bit misleading. Should have done the calculation for the x-intercept. Thank you.

I have a few more questions, though.
1. What is the code `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` for? How is it related to `\pgfplots` exactly?
2. In `\addplot[smooth,very thick,black,-]{f(x)};`, what is the function of the hyphen (-)?
3. Is there a documentation which outlines the commands and their functions for rendering graphs on the coordinate plane such as the one posted in the question?

Comment: @SamChoi `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` indicates the version. `pgfplots` has changed over the time. For instance, in much older versions we would have had to prepend the coordinates in the paths by `axis cs:` but from version `1.11` on this is no longer necessary. As for the hyphen: here we could drop it. It says something like "no arrows". If one uses `->` instead, there will be an arrow. If you have a scope with arrows, `-` says for this path one should not have an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

As pure TikZ picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=-(\x-(3/2))^2+(25/8);}]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw[very thick] 
    plot[domain=-0.5:3.5, samples=100] (\x,{f(\x)}); 
\node[above right,inner sep=1pt] at (2,{f(2)}) {$y=f(x)$};
\node[below left, inner sep=1pt] at (0,0) {$O$};
\draw[dashed] 
        (0,{f(3/2)}) node[left]  {$\frac{25}{8}$} 
    -|  (3/2,0)      node[below] {$\frac{ 3}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. You help is much appreciated.