# Not simply connected domain

Tags: draw, domain

Could someone help me drawing this picture?[image]

It should be a complex domain U, not simply connected (with two curves inside linked to the domain frontier with dashed lines)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You can just draw by hand, scan in the drawing, use includegraphics.

Comment: Thank everybody... I didn't have so deeply knowledge about tools used in your answers (and I made this question perhaps too soon after the previous, since I didn't see the answer: my fault, I am a new user) but I'm going to update my knowledge. In future I will surely share my attempts basing on what I have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this site is not to let someone else convert screen shots into LaTeX code. Rather, you should ask questions from which you and others can learn. For instance, this question can be answered with the very tools that were provided in an answer to your previous question. These tools comprise drawing irregular shapes and adding an arrow at some position of a path. (I did that very quickly.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.markings,intersections} %< added
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430239
    arc arrow/.style args={%
    to pos #1 with length #2}{
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{#2/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-\tmpArrowTime/3} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=#2,bend]}]       
        (@1) .. controls (@2) and (@3) .. (@4);},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },arr/.style={arc arrow=to pos #1 with length 2.3mm},
     set mark/.style args={#1/#2}{postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
     mark=at position #1 with {\coordinate(#2);}}}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr(\t)=2*(1+0.2*sin(2*\t+40)-0.3*sin(\t-10)+0.1*rnd);
f1(\t)=0.5*(1+0.2*sin(2*\t+120)+0.1*rnd);}]
  \pgfmathsetseed{42}
  \draw[set mark={0.05/p0},arr=0.1,set mark={0.23/p2},set mark={0.55/p3},set mark={0.8/p1}] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:{rr(\t)});
  \draw[rotate around={20:(-1.4,-1)},arr=0.65] (-1.4,-1) rectangle 
    ++ (0.8,0.6) (-1,-0.4) coordinate (q2) (-1,-1) coordinate (q3);
  \path (@2) node[above right] {$\gamma_1$};
  \draw[arr=0.3,set mark={0.65/q0},set mark={0.95/q1},xshift=1cm] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples
  at={0,45,...,315}] (-\t:{f1(\t)});
  \path (@2) node[below left] {$\gamma_2$};
  \path (45:2.8) node{$U$};
  \draw[dashed] (p0) -- (q0) (p1) -- (q1) (p2) -- (q2) (p3) -- (q3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The geometry of the domain is clearer if the domain is shaded.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay This can be achieved by simply adding `fill=gray!50`, say, to the `\draw` command of the respective domain.