# linear combination of cyclic text in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

latex code for this linear combination:[image]

I have this code for the cyclic text but I have no idea how to make a bunch of them as a linear combination.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->]
    \node (a) at (90:2cm)  {Democrat};
    \node (b) at (-30:2cm) {Republician};
    \node (c) at (210:2cm) {Third};
    
    \draw (-20:2cm) arc (-20:60:2cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 1}};
    \draw (120:2cm) arc (120:200:2cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize -1}};
    \draw (220:2cm) arc (220:320:2cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? Share your works.

Comment: I tried xshift and scope but didn't work the way I want.

Comment: Welcome! Please add some [minimal working code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) . For starting [eample1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254849/drawing-circular-arrows-between-nodes) or [example2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254849/drawing-circular-arrows-between-nodes) could help.

Comment: Showing code will speed up answers and increase their quality as a side-effect ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `tikzpicture` can be its own atom in a larger mathematical construct.  In this case, I also used `\raisebox` to get better centering.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$
5\cdot
\raisebox{-1.5cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,->]
    \node (a) at (90:2cm)  {Democrat};
    \node (b) at (-30:2cm) {Republician};
    \node (c) at (210:2cm) {Third};
    
    \draw (-20:2cm) arc (-20:60:2cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 5 voters}};
    \draw (120:2cm) arc (120:200:2cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize 7 voters}};
    \draw (220:2cm) arc (220:320:2cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1 voter}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
+4\cdot
\raisebox{-1.5cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,->]
    \node (a) at (90:2cm)  {Democrat};
    \node (b) at (-30:2cm) {Republician};
    \node (c) at (210:2cm) {Third};
    
    \draw (-20:2cm) arc (-20:60:2cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 5 voters}};
    \draw (120:2cm) arc (120:200:2cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize 7 voters}};
    \draw (220:2cm) arc (220:320:2cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1 voter}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
+\cdots + 2\cdot
\raisebox{-1.5cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,->]
    \node (a) at (90:2cm)  {Democrat};
    \node (b) at (-30:2cm) {Republician};
    \node (c) at (210:2cm) {Third};
    
    \draw (-20:2cm) arc (-20:60:2cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 5 voters}};
    \draw (120:2cm) arc (120:200:2cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize 7 voters}};
    \draw (220:2cm) arc (220:320:2cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1 voter}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, array}
 


\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{@{} *{1}{m{0.4cm}}*{1}{m{2cm}} *{1}{m{0.8cm}}*{1}{m{2cm}} *{1}{m{1.8cm}}*{1}{m{3cm}}*{1}{m{3cm}} @{}}

 5 $\cdot$& \begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=.7]
   \node (i) at (90:1cm)  {$T$};
   \node (j) at (-30:1cm) {$D$};
   \node (k) at (210:1cm) {$R$};
   \draw (70:1cm)  arc (70:-10:1cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 1}};
   \draw (-50:1cm) arc (-50:-130:1cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1}};
   \draw (190:1cm) arc (190:110:1cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize -1}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
&+ 4 $\cdot$& \begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=.7]
   \node (i) at (90:1cm)  {$T$};
   \node (j) at (-30:1cm) {$D$};
   \node (k) at (210:1cm) {$R$};
   \draw (70:1cm)  arc (70:-10:1cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 1}};
   \draw (-50:1cm) arc (-50:-130:1cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1}};
   \draw (190:1cm) arc (190:110:1cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize -1}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
&+ $ \ldots $ + 2 $\cdot$ & \begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=.7]
   \node (i) at (90:1cm)  {$T$};
   \node (j) at (-30:1cm) {$D$};
   \node (k) at (210:1cm) {$R$};
   \draw (70:1cm)  arc (70:-10:1cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 1}};
   \draw (-50:1cm) arc (-50:-130:1cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1}};
   \draw (190:1cm) arc (190:110:1cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize -1}};
\end{tikzpicture} \\




\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `longtable`?

Comment: @egreg To say the truth I have done template with "longtable" a few minutes ago, so I just didn't change it (the main thing is that it works))

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Another approach with a macro for the cyclic text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage   {tikz}   % nice drawings

\newcommand{\cyclic}[3]% numbers: top right, bottom, top left
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,baseline=(center.base)]% <-- to fix the baseline
    \useasboundingbox (-1.4,-1.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
    \node (center) at (0,0) {\strut};
    \foreach[count=\ii]\i/\j in {D/#1,T/#2,R/#3}
    {
      \draw    (120*\ii-20:1) arc (120*\ii-20:120*\ii+80:1);
      \node at (120*\ii-30:1)     {$\i$};
      \node at (120*\ii+30:1.3)   {\footnotesize\strut$\j\ifnum\j<0\hphantom{-}\fi$};
    }%                        this provides some symmetry ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] See the following equation:
\[5\cdot\cyclic{-1}{1}{1}+4\cdot\cyclic{-1}{-1}{1}+\cdots+2\cdot\cyclic{1}{-1}{-1}.\]

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can add more parameters if you need to change the letters D,T,R, the size, etc.