# cyclic and normal text in a table in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I need a table with this linear combination and text:[image]

I have the cyclic part from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628637/linear-combination-of-cyclic-text-in-latex)

but I don't know how to mix it all to have the table in the pic.

Comment: You could have linked everyone to your previous questions which are related to this one, in order to avoid members doing the job from scratch once again. Then, as you should have known, TeX-SE is not a `do it for me` website.  In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution.