# How to create an animated flowchart with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I need to draw a simple animated flow chart that describes the flow from each node to node.

[image]

In the picture timeframe, denotes how the flow of the animation.

Comment: Welcome! I think no one here has objections, please go ahead. ;-) More seriously, please show us what you have tried. See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78318) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger's cat it really helps. Can you please tell me, how can I rotate the dotted box?

Comment: The animation can be made with beamer's built-in command `\animate` and a `dash pattern` that depends on it. However, you expecting those who may spell this out to create this flow chart, which involves punching in texts from a screen shot, which not too many are excited about.

Comment: Okay thanks. Let me try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This just spells out the comment. If you have some sort of a flow diagram, one can add this flowing frame there. One may want to play with the parameters to make it more fancy/appealing, but this illustrates how this could work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcount\ww
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An animated dash pattern}
\animate<2-49>
\animatevalue<1-50>{\ww}{1}{50}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydash}{\ww/25}
 \draw[dash pattern=on 0.001pt off \mydash pt on 2pt] (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also animate the `dash phase`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\newcount\ww
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An animated dash pattern}
\animate<2-19> % <-increase 19 to make the animation last longer
\animatevalue<1-20>{\ww}{1}{20} % <- 210 is 19+1, so increase
\transduration<1-20>{0.4}% <- 20 is 19+1, so increase; controls the speed
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=N,nodes=draw,>=stealth]
  \begin{scope}[start chain=going below,nodes={on chain,join,draw},
  every join/.style={->},node distance=4mm]
   \node[ellipse,alias=N0] {Start};
   \node[alias=N1] {Wurzelbrumpf};
   \node[alias=OCM] {OCM};
   \node[alias=O2] {O2};
   \node[alias=N3] {Output};
   \node[alias=N4] {Stop};
  \end{scope}
  \node[left=of O2] (O1) {O1};
  \node[right=of O2] (O3) {O3};
  \draw[->] (OCM) -- (O1);
  \draw[->] (OCM) -- (O3);
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydashphase}{\ww/5} 
  \node[fit=(OCM) (O1) (O3),inner sep=1ex,
    dash=on 2.0pt off 2.0pt phase \mydashphase pt](N2){};
 \end{scope}
 \path foreach \X in {0,...,4}
 {(N\X-|N.west) node[left]{$t=\ifnum\X=0
 0
 \else
 t+\X
 \fi$}};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The speed here is controlled by the conversion to gif, in your beamer animation you need to go to full screen mode, use acroread and you can set the `\transduration` to control the speed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Schrödinger's cat